# Trying to pass string after # in URL to a PHP variable

Tags: javascript, php, magento

I am trying to find a way to do this but I know I can't do this the way I was trying to because of server side (php) vs client side (js).

I am trying to get the variable after the # sign in the url, for example if it was www.test.com/hello#4213 I would want to get the string 4213. So far I have used the following function

```
function GetURLParameter(sParam) {
    var sPageURL = window.location.hash.substring(1);
    var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
        var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
        if (sParameterName[0] == sParam) {
            return sParameterName[1];
        }
    }
}
```

Now the problem is I am trying to put this into a PHP variable that I need so that I can get information about the product. To be more specific I am using this in Magento to get the SKU after the # sign and then dynamically create a page with the photo and image. So far I have all the code working other than this part.

**The question is How can I pass the JS variable to PHP**?

Thanks!

Comment: if you are creating the link, the obvious answer is to not use the #

Comment: Is there a compelling reason to use the # instead of a standard query string? Is this in a single page app type of execution?

Comment: What @providencemac is true.  It seems like you're over complicating things.  Why not use `mysite.com?sku=12345` and retrieve the value through `$_GET['sku']`?

Answer (score 0):

what, you want 4213 is js, then:

```
var str="www.test.com/hello#4213";
var n=str.lastIndexOf("#") + 1;
alert(str.substring(n));
```

you haven't explained clearly how you will pass js vars back to php, maybe a clearer explaination would be good

Comment: Thanks, that is what I am trying to figure out. How I pass the JS variable back into PHP

Answer (score 0):

try with this code, May be its help you

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.observe('dom:loaded', function(){
    var pageURL = window.location.href;
    var lastStr = pageURL.lastIndexOf("#") + 1;
    alert(pageURL.substring(lastStr));
});
</script>
```